# How can this instrumentation be done

Tags: java, classloader, bytecode, instrumentation

I have different Java applications running on my system and want to instrument classes from one of these applications

While trying to do this using dynamically loaded Java agent I found that we can attach it to a `jvm` instance which requires `vm` `id` of that `jvm` instance when I put a `pid` of an already running Java application by searching from windows task manager the agent jar does not attach to this process and a error is thrown.

While doing it using `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()` the process `id()` returned is that of the instance loading the `agent.jar`. kindly suggest how to access a `vmid` of a different `jvm` instance

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripts for executing the **JPS** command and extract the information regarding the VM instances being run.

Also the jps command uses [MonitoredHost](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/serviceability/jvmstat/sun/jvmstat/monitor/MonitoredHost.html) API which has [activeVms()](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/serviceability/jvmstat/sun/jvmstat/monitor/MonitoredHost.html#activeVms%28%29) method.